# Displaying contents of an associated model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm hacking away at my first serious attempt at a rails app and have run into a little trouble.

I have two models, one called `LegalForm` and the other one called `Question`.  One contains a list of different forms and the other contains the questions associated with each.  Or, as I've stated in my `legal_form.rb`

```
class LegalForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end
```

**Each database table is set up as follows:**

```
mysql> select * from questions;
+----+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | legalform_id | question_number | question_type | the_question                                                        | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |            1 |               1 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  2 |            1 |               2 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  3 |            1 |               3 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  4 |            1 |               4 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  5 |            1 |               5 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  6 |            1 |               6 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  7 |            1 |               7 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  8 |            1 |               8 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
|  9 |            1 |               9 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
| 10 |            1 |              10 | lorem         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 | 2014-11-20 21:27:04 |
+----+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from legal_forms;                                                                                                                                                   
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+                                                                                                           
| id | title      | company | created_at          | updated_at          |                                                                                                           
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | First_Form |       1 | 2014-11-20 20:58:53 | 2014-11-20 20:58:53 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**What I'd like to do** Is to display questions 1-10, as presented above, on the show view for legal_forms.

To this end, I've set up my `legal_forms_controller.rb` as follows:

```
class LegalFormsController < ApplicationController
  def index
@legal_forms=LegalForm.all
  end

  def ufilter
  end

  def own
  end

  def show
@legalform = LegalForm.find(params[:id])
@questions = @legalform.questions
  end

  private
  def legal_forms_params
params.require(:legalform).permit(:title, :company)
  end
end
```

And have set up my `show.html.erb` file like this:

```
<h1>LegalForms#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/legal_forms/show.html.erb</p>
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<span><%= question.the_question %> </span>
<% end %>
```

However, when I navigate to the page at `localhost:3000/legal_forms/1`, I am faced with the following errors:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in LegalForms#show
>   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'questions.legal_form_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions`  WHERE `questions`.`legal_form_id` = 1

The error message pins the matter on the loop (which makes sense given the sql error).  I've clearly got the wrong idea about something in here.  Any help getting on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have an issue with the name of your column.

You column name is `legalform_id` and you request `legal_form_id`.

I don't know how you defined your Question model, but there is something fishy over there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use has_many association in model - for default the foreing key is    model_name_id
You need to add foreing_key to your has_many assotiation as `legalform_id` or rename column in database to `legal_form_id`